# Flickering / fragmentary visuals for USDZ file when viewing placed PNG

Tags: augmented-reality, sketchup, usdz

Project: Creating a basic cube with png’s imported and placed onto the faces

Done in SketchUp 2015
Exported to USDZ using Simlab USDZ exporter

When viewed in AR mode, images flicker and are shown in a kind of interlaced pattern

Better when in “object” view (non AR)

Basic question is: are placed images generally not a good idea for USDZ, or is it just something I’m doing with my limited toolset.

[image: iphone 11 AR screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The image was apparently interfering with the surface behind it.  Removing the cube and retaining the photos works perfectly.